# Address Book callback not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I have an iPhone app that makes use of the AddressBook.framework and uses Core Data to store these contacts. In order to make sure I update my own database when the Address Book is updated (whether via MobileMe or editing within my own app), I am subscribing to the notification as to when the Address Book is updating. I call this on startup:

```
ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(book, addressBookChanged, self);
```

Which (supposedly) calls this on any editing. I have an ABPersonViewController which allows editing, and addressBookChanged never seems to get called.

```
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef reference, CFDictionaryRef dictionary, void *context) {
    // The contacts controller we need to call
    ContactsController *contacts = (ContactsController *)context;

    // Sync with the Address Book
    [contacts synchronizeWithAddressBook:reference];
}
```

Is there any reason for it to not be called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the reason it wasn't getting called was a simple mistake. I did:

```
CFRelease(book);
```

After setting the notification. I removed that and it's now getting called.