# ABAddressBook external callback not called in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

I have a class holding the list of contacts of my user in an iPhone app.

The core of it is implemented as follows.

```
//file Contacts.m
//imports here
    void MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback (
                                              ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
                                              CFDictionaryRef info,
                                              void *context
                                              )
    {
        NSLog(@"callback called ");
        [[Contacts sharedInstance] refresh];
    }

@implementation Contacts
@synthesize addressBook;

+ (Contacts*)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedInstance == nil)
        {
            sharedInstance = [[Contacts alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)refresh
{
    ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook); /*refreshing the address book in case of changes*/
   [people release];
    people = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

}

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        sharedInstance = self;
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();;
        people = nil;                                                               
        [self refresh];
        ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback (      addressBook,
                                                           MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback,
                                                          self
                                                          );
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

In `init`, I setup an external callback `MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback` to be notified of changes to the contact list. 
The problem that I have is that the external callback is not called (I never see the result of the nslog message) when I add a contact in the iPhone phone app.

What did I do wrong ?

Added note: even stranger, if I do

```
ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook);
```

every time my app come to the front and the address book has been modified, then the callback is called.

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706641/address-book-callback-not-called

Comment: Yep, seen that, but I don't release my address book as in this question, so I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested this on my iPhone and verified that the callback was called:

Contacts.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

@interface Contacts : NSObject
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
    NSArray *people;
}

+ (Contacts*)sharedInstance;
- (void)refresh;

void MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback (
                                          ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
                                          CFDictionaryRef info,
                                          void *context
                                          );

@end
```

Contacts.m:

```
#import "Contacts.h"

void MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback (
                                          ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
                                          CFDictionaryRef info,
                                          void *context
                                          )
{
    NSLog(@"callback called ");
    [[Contacts sharedInstance] refresh];
}

@implementation Contacts

+ (Contacts*)sharedInstance
{
    static Contacts *sharedInstance = nil;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedInstance == nil)
        {
            sharedInstance = [[Contacts alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)refresh
{
    ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook); /*refreshing the address book in case of changes*/
    [people release];
    people = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

}

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        //sharedInstance = self;
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        people = nil;                                                               
        [self refresh];
        ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback (addressBook,
                                                     MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback,
                                                     self
                                                     );
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You just put code without comments. I guess you wrote this, ran it and  verified that the callback was called ? Am I correct ?

Comment: Correct. I tested it on my iPhone and verified that the callback was called.

Comment: @Marco is it required that this code for addressbook stays in app delegate file or any other controller file that is always called so that callback is called?

Comment: @meteors have you tried that? What are the results?

Comment: @Marco I have a separate file called Contacts.h/m. There is a function fetchContacts where I use ABAddressBookCreate and store contacts to local database. Here only I have defined and registered for callback. From my base view controller the function in this file just gets called once. Doing so I never receive the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I'm about four years late to the party and this interface has now been deprecated... but in case anybody still cares, in my case I found that you need to register for the callback on the main thread.  If I registered on a different thread, it just never got called.  Don't see that in the docs (though maybe that's just a reading comprehension fail on my part).

Anyway, try that.